# Reading the SAML token response objects using openAM?

Tags: saml-2.0, openam

I have a saml2.0 response token from IDP and I am using OpenAM as a Service provider. I want to read the SAML using openAM Java api and validate the response. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything manual, if OpenAM is the SP it will consume the SAML assertions from the IdP just fine.